# best Approach for Catching exception from my model class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got lost on what/where/when i should catch exceptions inside my asp.net mvc web application. and how to display error messages for end users. For example i got the following Action method:-

```
    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ServerToEdit serverToEdit)
        {
try
        { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
         {
         if (!(repository.IsIPUnique(serverToEdit.TechnologyIP.IPAddress, 0)))
        {
        ModelState.AddModelError("TechnologyIP.IPAddress", "Error occured. The Same IP might already assinged.");

                           return View(serverToEdit);
        }
        if (!(repository.IsServerNameUnique(serverToEdit.Server.Name, 0)))
        {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Server.Name", "Error occured. The Same Server Name might already assinged.");

                           return View(serverToEdit);
                       }
                        repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(serverToEdit.Server,serverToEdit.TechnologyIP,User.Identity.Name);
                        repository.Save();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }

        else 
        {
        return View(serverToEdit);
        }
        }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occured. The Same IP/Name might already assinged.");

        }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException)
                   {
                       ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occured. User might not be defiend inside Active Directory.");

                   }
         return View(serverToEdit);
        }
```

I have the following questions regarding my code:-

1. i have two services methods (IsIPUnique & IsServeNameUnique); but is the Controller action method that best place to call these service methods from my repository model class?
2. currently if the service method fail, i am manually writing the model state error and return the view to the user. so is this the right way to write model state errors for the service methods?
3. if the DBUpdateException was raised, i am assuming that either the IP or serve-name already exists in the database (This might happen if the service methods fail to check in a high traffic application). but there are many other reasons for the DBUpdateExceptio to be raised. so my question is about what is the best approach to handle the DBUpdateException . and show exactly the reason it was raised for?

Answer (score 1):

The controller is usually the right place to do your model state validation, but, as I discovered, if you're doing a lot of validation then it can easily bloat up your controller.

How I deal with validation heavy controller methods is to export the validation to a service, say a static method called ValidateServer(serverToEdit).

Then inside this method, run all your various checks, and build up a Dictionary called errors, and add an error to this dictionary if the check fails.

Then you can pass this dictionary back to your controller, and add the errors to ModelState using a foreach. This then leaves you with just your exception handling.

For serving the user info on your DBUpdateException, you should be able to get information on why it occurred via the exceptions .InnerException property, which you could pass to the user as your error message. So you would write:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
               {
                   ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occurred:" + ex.InnerException);

               }
```

Or something along those lines!

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i think that ex.InnerException , will contain a technical error description . so is it normal to display this error to the user, Or it will be betterto manipulate these errors , before displaying them to the users.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix validation with exception handling.

It makes more sense to handle the exception in one centralized place and log and display errors to the end users. That way, you make your code much more readable and maintainable.  CodeProject has [a great article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422572/Exception-Handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC) on this subject.

Comment: Your link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add another tier that wraps the calls and get back the result with some state and the error if any, and use modelstate in case of failure with the returned message, in this way your controller would be more readable.